# how to display particular event in calendar programmatically?

Tags: android

I have an application, in that i need to add the events to the device calendar. If event title are already adjust in calendar, I need to show it.
How can i achieve this? I am using the following code to go to the event but it not working!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                // Android 2.2+
                intent.setData(Uri
                        .parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/"
                                + String.valueOf(CustomCalendar.eventID
                                        .get(position))));


                // Android 2.1 and below.
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
```